# How to add vertical space between inputs in a form?

Tags: html, css

I have a form, but somewhy the inputs doesn't have any vertical space, so it's not separated with each other.

Interesting thing that it has some space in my code snippet, but not in my environment.

Could someone tell me how to add some more vertical space here?

I've tried to add `line-height` to class `form-example`, but it had no effect.
Here's my form:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
    <table>
        <tr class="edit-form-standard-dauer">
            <td>
                <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="edit-form-verlangerung-dauer">
            <td>
                <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: you can simply use the margin like this tr{margin:20px 0px;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`border-collapse: separate;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp) and
    [`border-spacing: 1em;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp) to your `table`

```css
.table-border{
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
        <table class="table-border">
            <tr class="edit-form-standard-dauer">
                <td>
                    <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="edit-form-verlangerung-dauer">
                <td>
                    <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: But in your snippet it seems that text with the input is not equal. Some text are lower than the inputs.

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks. Could you tell me if this css will be applied to all the tables that insert this css file or just this one?

Comment: to all so be more spesific and set `class/id` to table ... see edit

Answer (score 1):

try to set padding for `td` to get the spacing. Within the table its complicated to add margin.

```css
td {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
   <table>
        <tr class="edit-form-standard-dauer">
            <td>
                <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="edit-form-verlangerung-dauer">
            <td>
                <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```